# dynamically select column name that changed

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table as shown below.

### ID      NAME       ADDRESS       CITY     ROLE         Date_Modified

1       Tom        something     austin   manager         X

2       Tom        nothing       austin   principal       Y

3       Tom        anything      dallas   VP              Z

How do write a query to select the column name that have changed between entries 1,2 and 3? Currently I am building a report that needs to identify change. This is what I have so far and need to work with it.

I need to be able to detect via stored proc and see output below.

### Id  ColumnName  DateChanged

2    Address         Y

2    Role            Y

3    Address         Z

3    Role            Z

Comment: looks like you will need to use a trigger.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: I will be doing that going forward...right now the need is to report on legacy data.

Comment: so does your table hold historical data or simply updates the field by overwriting the data within the field?

Comment: In the above, I am already querying an audit table(poor design!!) which only maintains snapshot of the state. It simply updates the fields. It doesnt have any information on what has been changed.However it has timestamp and the user who updated it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, what you need is detecting changes from one row to another and unpivoting the data. Usage of LAG required SQL Server 2012 or more.

```
;with cte as (
    -- LAG for id is used to skip first row from selection
    select id, LAG(id, 1) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS OldId, 
        address, LAG(address, 1) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS OldAddress, 
        role, LAG(role, 1) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS OldRole,
        Date_Modified
    from audit_data
)
SELECT id, ColName, data_col, Date_Modified
FROM
(
    select id, address, role, Date_Modified
    from cte
    -- detect any change in monitored data
    where ((OldAddress IS NULL OR address <> OldAddress)
        OR (OldRole IS NULL OR role <> OldRole))
        AND OldId IS NOT NULL
) AS cp
-- unpivot address and role into data_col column
UNPIVOT 
(
  data_col FOR ColName IN (address, role)
) AS up;
```

Data used for setup:

```
-- drop table audit_data
create table audit_data (
    id int,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    address VARCHAR(100),
    city varchar(100),
    role VARCHAR(100),
    Date_Modified DATETIME2
)



insert into audit_data values (1, 'Tom', 'something', 'austin', 'manager', '20150103'),
    (2, 'Tom', 'nothing', 'austin', 'principa', '20150205'),
    (3, 'Tom', 'anything', 'dallas', 'VP', '20150314')
go
```

**[Edit] SQL 2008R2 version:**

```
;with ad_cte as (
    select id, address, role, Date_Modified, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) RowNo
    from audit_data
),
cte as (
    select ad.id,
        ad.address, ad_old.address AS OldAddress, 
        ad.role, ad_old.role AS OldRole,
        ad.Date_Modified
    from ad_cte ad
        join ad_cte ad_old on ad_old.RowNo + 1 = ad.RowNo
)
SELECT id, ColName, data_col, Date_Modified
FROM
(
    select id, address, role, Date_Modified
    from cte
    -- detect any change in monitored data
    where ((OldAddress IS NULL OR address <> OldAddress)
        OR (OldRole IS NULL OR role <> OldRole))
        -- this should be changed for generality
        AND cte.id > 1
) AS cp
-- unpivot address and role into data_col column
UNPIVOT 
(
  data_col FOR ColName IN (address, role)
) AS up;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However I am using sql server 2008 r2 as tagged earlier in the question. How do i retrieve old and new values with the column name that has changed?.

Comment: On SQL2008 R2 you can replace LAG with self joins: audit_data joins with itself based on ad.id = ad_old.id - 1 (only if you know that ids do not have gaps). I will try to edit the answer with the legacy query as soon as I have some time.

Comment: I have added a legacy query, It should work regardless of gaps existence within your ids.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to Alexei's answer:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp( ID            INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
                    NAME          VARCHAR(30),
                    ADDRESS       VARCHAR(30),
                    CITY          VARCHAR(30),
                    ROLE          VARCHAR(30),
                    Date_Modified DATETIME );

INSERT INTO #temp
       SELECT 'Tom',
              'something',
              'austin',
              'manager',
              DATEADD(day, -3, GETDATE())
       UNION
       SELECT 'Tom',
              'nothing',
              'austin',
              'principal',
              DATEADD(day, -2, GETDATE())
       UNION
       SELECT 'Tom',
              'anything',
              'dallas',
              'VP',
              DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE());

SELECT 'Jon',
       'something',
       'san antonio',
       'assistant manager',
       DATEADD(day, -3, GETDATE())
UNION
SELECT 'Jon',
       'something',
       'austin',
       'assistant manager',
       DATEADD(day, -2, GETDATE())
UNION
SELECT 'Jon',
       'anything',
       'dallas',
       'manager',
       DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE());

SELECT id,
       ColName,
       Date_Modified
FROM( 
      SELECT DISTINCT B.ID,
                      B.Name,
                        CASE
                            WHEN A.ADDRESS <> B.ADDRESS
                            THEN B.ADDRESS
                        END AS ADDRESS,
                        CASE
                            WHEN A.CITY <> B.CITY
                            THEN B.CITY
                        END AS CITY,
                        CASE
                            WHEN A.ROLE <> B.ROLE
                            THEN B.ROLE
                        END AS ROLE,
                      B.Date_Modified
      FROM(
               SELECT *,
                      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY Date_Modified DESC) AS ROWNUM
               FROM #temp ) AS A
          INNER JOIN(
               SELECT *,
                      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY Date_Modified DESC) AS ROWNUM
               FROM #temp ) AS B ON A.NAME = B.NAME
                                AND CHECKSUM(A.NAME, A.ADDRESS, A.CITY, A.ROLE) <> CHECKSUM(B.NAME, B.ADDRESS, B.CITY, B.ROLE)
                                AND A.ROWNUM = B.ROWNUM - 1 ) AS cp
    UNPIVOT( data FOR ColName IN( address,
                                      role )) AS up;
```

Comment: I added a few more entries to make sure it applies to the whole set.